# Angularjs unit test failed dependencies in Jasmine karma unit tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm newer to unit test using jasmine and karma,I want to test my service that consume an api rest but when I try to mock my module I alway get the some message instanctation failed in my terminal when I run my test using karma this is my files :

My module :

```
    'use strict';
    // create the module and name it mainAPp
    var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute','LocalStorageModule','jkAngularRatingStars']);
    // configure routes
    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })
            .when('/login', {
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                controller  : 'loginController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });

    })
;
```

And this the service that I want to test using jasmine

```
'use strict';
app.factory('authService', ['$http', '$q', '$log', 'localStorageService', function ($http, $q, $log, localStorageService) {

    // base  authentification url 
    var serviceBase = 'http://localhost:3000/user/auth';
    var serviceLogOutUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/user/logout';
    var authServiceFactory = {};
    var _authentication = {
        isAuth: false,
        userName: "",
        status: ""
    }

    //User authentification 
    var _login = function (loginData) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post(serviceBase, loginData, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.status == "success") {
                localStorageService.set('sessionId', { sessionId: response.data.sessionId, userName: loginData.username });
                _authentication.userName = loginData.username;
                _authentication.isAuth = true;
            }
            else {
                _logOut();
            }
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }).catch(function (err, status) {
            _logOut();
            //$log.log('authentification failed.');
            deferred.reject(err);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
    // fill data 
    var _fillAuthData = function () {
        var authData = localStorageService.get('sessionId');
        if (authData) {
            _authentication.isAuth = true;
            _authentication.userName = authData.userName;
        }

    }
    // check if the user is loged
    var _islogin = function () {
        _fillAuthData();
        return _authentication.isAuth;
    };

    // logout function
    var _logOut = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (localStorageService.get('sessionId') != null) {
            var sessionId = localStorageService.get('sessionId').sessionId;
            $http.get(serviceLogOutUrl + "?sessionId=" + sessionId, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }).then(function (response) {
                localStorageService.remove('sessionId');
                _authentication.isAuth = false;
                _authentication.userName = "";
                if (response.status = "success") {
                    //$log.log('logout success.');
                }
                else {
                    //$log.log('logout failed.');
                }
                deferred.resolve(response);

            }).catch(function (err, status) {
                localStorageService.remove('sessionId');
                _authentication.isAuth = false;
                _authentication.userName = "";
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };


    authServiceFactory.login = _login;
    authServiceFactory.islogin = _islogin;
    authServiceFactory.fillAuthData = _fillAuthData;
    authServiceFactory.logOut = _logOut;

    return authServiceFactory;
}]);
```

And this is my My jasmine **specRunner.html**  :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.6.3</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.6.3/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine-2.6.3/jasmine.css">

  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.6.3/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.6.3/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.6.3/boot.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-mocks.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/rating-stars.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/app.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/authService.js"></script>
   <script src="lib/angular/loginController.js"></script> 
  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script src="src/calculator.js"></script>


  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script src="spec/calculator.spec.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And this my karma config part
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser

files: [
  'lib/angular/angular.js',
  'lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
  'lib/angular/angular-route.js',
  'lib/angular/rating-stars.js',
  'lib/angular/angular-local-storage.min.js',
  'lib/angular/app.js',
  'lib/angular/authService.js',
  'lib/angular/loginController.js',
  'src/**/*.js',
  'spec/***/.js'
],

And this my unit test that doesn't run because of failed instanciation due to  my module :

```
describe("Services", function () {
  var service, $httpBackend;
    beforeEach(function(){
        angular.mock.module('ngRoute', []);
        angular.mock.module('LocalStorageModule', []);
        angular.mock.module('jkAngularRatingStars', []);
       module('mainApp', ['ngRoute','LocalStorageModule','jkAngularRatingStars']);
        module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('authService', service);
    });
    });
    describe("auth services", function () {


        beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
            service = $injector.get('authService');
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

            $httpBackend.when('POST', "http://localhost:3000/user/auth").respond('{ "status": "success", "sessionId": "a8t9Rr9bjWD2InfeFLbNS3FNg5mnFqiV", "username": "ali" }');
        }));

        afterEach(function() {
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        });

        it('login - should return auth success', function () {
            service.login().then(function(response) {
                expect(response.status).toEqual('success');
            });
            $httpBackend.flush();
        });


    });
});
```

This my karma config js :

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Tue Jun 27 2017 13:17:32 GMT+0000 (WET)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'lib/angular/angular.js',
      'lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
      'lib/angular/angular-route.js',
      'lib/angular/rating-stars.js',
      'lib/angular/angular-local-storage.min.js',
      'lib/angular/app.js',
      'lib/angular/authService.js',
      'lib/angular/loginController.js',
      'src/**/*.js',
      'spec/**/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Can some one helpe me fixing this problem thanx in advance

Comment: Could we see your whole karma configuration file? It's probably coming from over there.

Comment: I add it  to my question